# android spinner items not displaying when clicked in fragment activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have written following code for spinner in new fragment activity.
But on clicking the spinner arrow, items are not displaying.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


    spinner=(Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(),R.array.areas,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is setcontentView(R.layout.yourlayout) ? use spinner in yourlayout.xml file and define that in setcontentView.

Comment: Thanks . Actually the way it worked was adding this "android:entries="@array/areas""in <Spinner> xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

Please find the below link for more info on the above method.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)